# Get count of HttpCollectionKeys

Tags: asp.net

I'm getting the `ThrowIfMaxHttpCollectionKeysExceeded()` error on a particularly large page, and wanted to know if there was a way to **count the number of HttpCollectionKeys** my page actually contains before it is submitted.

I want to use this information to try and avoid increasing the MaxHttpCollectionKeys, so **NOT** this.

```
<add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="3000" />
```

Thank you for any information on how to achieve this.

**UPDATE:**

It turns out `Page.Request.Form.Keys.Count` is the field I was looking for. I had tried this before, but I was accessing it during Page_Load, and apparently you have to access this **during a post back event** to get a correct number, which means you have to temporarily set:

```
<add key="aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys" value="3000" />.
```

There is still the question of how to access this value before submitting the page, but this is how I was able to get some kind of count at least.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an HttpModule that will count the number of keys in each request and record the "high-water mark" of keys used and in the Windows event log:

[Using an HTTP Module to assist in adjusting the value of aspnet:MaxHttpCollectionKeys](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/paulking/archive/2012/01/16/using-an-http-module-to-assist-in-adjusting-the-value-of-aspnet-maxhttpcollectionkeys-imposed-by-ms11-100.aspx)

Comment: Thank you for the module, but I'd rather just access a field that can tell me at that particular moment. I actually have the page that will give the highest number. After reading the article it actually helped me find what I think is the correct field.